# When did the Talmudic penalty of death stop being carried out?

Tags: history, death, beit-din-court

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [History of Capital Punishment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4077/history-of-capital-punishment)

When did the Talmudic penality of death stop being carried out? For example, the opening verses of Tractate Sotah describe death penalty for adultery.