# How does one get punished for sins beyond punishment?

Tags: sin, reward-punishment

I asked this question in a [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100197/which-sins-are-beyond-punishment#comment335075_100204) to another [question's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100197/which-sins-are-beyond-punishment) answer, but I wanted to ask it explicitly:

It has been stated that :

> [...] it has been pointed out in Rishonim [...] that some sins are so bad they can't get a punishment - because the punishment creates forgiveness, but when the sin is too great, forgiveness is not an option.

If so, what happens to the one who commits such a sin?

Is he punished in the afterlife instead of by humans in this world? But that would also be a punishment/kaparah and hence affect forgiveness. Or is he not punished anywhere (this world or the next world)? That doesn't make sense as well - since then he gets off scot free.

Answer (score 1):

The [Derech Hashem](https://www.sefaria.org/Derech_Hashem%2C_Part_Two%2C_On_Mankind_in_This_World.3?with=all&lang=bi) states quite clearly that those whom are too evil to get cleansed through punishment are rewarded in this world for any good they may have done and are completely removed from existence after death.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Eliezer and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that God can punish with no forgiveness, so possibly those "too sinful to get punished (by humans)", can still be punished by God, with no forgiveness.

few examples:

ישעיהו סו  כד

> יָצְא֣וּ וְרָא֔וּ בְּפִגְרֵי֙ הָאֲנָשִׁ֔ים הַפֹּשְׁעִ֖ים בִּ֑י כִּ֣י
>   תוֹלַעְתָּ֞ם לֹ֣א תָמ֗וּת וְאִשָּׁם֙ לֹ֣א תִכְבֶּ֔ה וְהָי֥וּ דֵרָא֖וֹן
>   לְכָל־בָּשָֽׂר׃

Ishaia 66:24

They shall go out and gaze On the corpses of the men who rebelled against Me: Their worms shall not die, Nor their fire be quenched; They shall be a horror To all flesh.

> משנה סנהדרין י ב
>
> שלשה מלכים וארבעה הדיוטות אין להם חלק לעולם הבא.
>
> שלשה מלכים, ירבעם, אחאב, ומנשה. ... ארבעה הדיוטות, בלעם, ודואג,
>   ואחיתופל, וגחזי.

Mishna Sanhedrin  10:2

Three kings and for commoners has no part to the world-to-come
Three kings : Yeravam Ahab and Menashe...
Four commoners: Bilam ,Doeg, Achitofel And Gehazi

And we know that Bilam , for example still suffers (together with Jesus and Titus):

גיטיו נו ב: - נז א

> אסקיה לבלעם בנגידא ...א"ל דיניה דההוא גברא במאי א"ל בשכבת זרע רותחת

Gitin 56:b-57:a

[Aunkelus] raised Bilam with necromancy... asked him, what is your punishment? he replayed [being boiled] with hot semen

Comment: The quote in my question stated -  "some sins are so bad they can't get a punishment". But in the cases you cite they *are* receiving punishment (whether with forgiveness or without).

Comment: @user9806  "some sins are so bad they can't get a punishment" - you meant by humans - like in the case you brought from whoever practice Molech worship. I showed that it's possible to be punished in the after life with no forgiveness. I will edit my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Ok, but also it does not follow from the quotes your bring that there is no forgiveness. All they show is that the punishment is very long.

Comment: What do you mean "Bilam" "together with" Jesus?

Comment: @SolaGratia Judaism condemns Jesus as a heretic.

Comment: I know that much, I'm wondering why you distinguish between Bilam and Jesus here, whereas Bilam stands for Jesus?

Comment: @SolaGratia The passage talks about Titus and Jesus afterwards.

Comment: @Alaychem Also, it doesn't make much sense : why should punishment by humans bring forgiveness, but punishment by G-d not? If anything, human punishment seems relatively less severe (e.g. quick death by the court) than the Heavenly punishment (prolonged suffering, etc.).

Comment: @user9806 I didn't say that God's punishment is **always** with no forgiveness, I just say that he CAN punish with no forgiveness

Comment: @Alaychem I understand, what I'm saying is that it is strange to say that for some (really bad) sins punishment by humans (which is relatively quick and painless) is avoided in order to not give the sinner forgiveness, but yet punishment by heaven (more prolonged and with more suffering) is meted out without giving the sinner forgiveness. In these instances too, it seems like punishment should effect forgiveness, especially since the punishment is stronger in quantity/quality.